# SQL Server 2008 - Alternatives to While Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, while-loop

I have an INSERT statement that operates within a WHILE loop. In each iteration of the WHILE loop, some functions are called with dates variables passed as parameters. These date variables increase by one day at each iteration of the loop.

This is a stripped down example:

```
-- Start and End Date
DECLARE 
     @StartDate DATE = '20170101'
    ,@EndDate   DATE = '20170110'

-- Initialise Loop variables to Start Date
DECLARE
     @InsertDate  DATE = @StartDate
    ,@NextDate    DATE = @StartDate  

-- Loop for All Dates
WHILE (@InsertDate <> @EndDate)
BEGIN
     -- Gather Data to Insert
     INSERT INTO tblCombinedData
     SELECT 
         a.SomeString
        ,b.SomeNumber
        ,dbo.fnDoSomeStuff(a.AKey,@InsertDate,@NextDate)
        ,dbo.fnDoSomeMoreStuff(b.AKey,@InsertDate,@NextDate)
    FROM
        tblATable a 
    INNER JOIN tblAnotherTable b 
        ON a.ID = b.ID

    -- Move to next Set of Dates
    SET @InsertDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@InsertDate)
    SET @NextDate   = DATEADD(DAY,1,@InsertDate)
END
```

Is There a more efficient way of achieving this combined insert? (possibly via a CTE?) Thanks.

Note: (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Just create a table that has one row per date, then you can just run the SQL once. You could probably change the scalar functions too, since those can cause you problems as well.

Comment: I cannot alter the functions as there as in the real-life code there are quite a few of them. Also there is no dates in the remaining data to join on

Comment: I mean you need to create either a real table, a temporary table or some kind of tally with the dates, then you can join that with your SQL and get it done in one execution. Not sure if that will improve anything, since scalar functions are going to turn it to row-by-row execution.

Comment: what is the logic behind `@NextDate`? since it is the same date as `@InsertDate`

Comment: NextData is InsertDate + 1 Day, since it's called after the first DATEADD on InsertDay, a second effectively adds another day

Comment: @JamesZ The problem is, even if I create a table of dates, I have no way to join that back to my data as there are no corresponding dates in the data

Comment: Sure you can. Apply a ROW_NUMBER() to each table.

Comment: But you still might be trying to solve the wrong problem. The issue could still be the functions, especially if they are complex and each insert produces a lot of rows -- and you don't see the impact in query plan or statistics io, you need to look into plan cache.

Comment: `even if I create a table of dates, I have no way to join that back` - this is `CROSS JOIN` what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **ad-hoc Tally Table** in concert with a **CROSS APPLY**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '20170101'
Declare @Date2 date = '20170110'

-- Insert Into tblCombinedData
Select B.*
 From (Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(DD,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),@Date1) From  master..spt_values) DT
 Cross Apply (
                 SELECT a.SomeString
                       ,b.SomeNumber
                       ,dbo.fnDoSomeStuff(a.AKey,DT.D,DT.D)     --<< Notice DT.D
                       ,dbo.fnDoSomeMoreStuff(b.AKey,DT.D,DT.D) --<< Notice DT.D
                  FROM  tblATable a 
                  INNER JOIN tblAnotherTable b ON a.ID = b.ID
             ) B
```

If it helps with the visualization, the ad-hoc tally table looks like this

```
D
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05
2017-01-06
2017-01-07
2017-01-08
2017-01-09
2017-01-10
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, great solution!

Comment: @JamieStuartRobinParsons Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

Calendar CTE, anyone?

```
with CTE as
(
select @startdate as InsertDay
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, @startdate)
from CTE
where @startdate < @enddate
)

insert into tblCombinedData
select a1.stuff, fn(a1.stuff2, InsertDay, dateadd(day,1,InsertDay))
from CTE
cross join 
(
select stuff, stuff2
from tab1
inner join tab2
on tab1.thing = tab2.thing
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way....

```
declare @table1 table (dt datetime)
declare @table2 table (notDT char)

insert into @table1 (dt) values
('1/1/2017'),
('1/2/2017'),
('1/3/2017'),
('1/4/2017')


insert into @table2 (notDT) values
('a'),
('b'),
('c')


;with t2 as(
    select 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as rn
    from @table2),

t1 as(
    select 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by dt) as rn
    from @table1)


select 
    t2.notDT,
    t1.dt
from
    t2
    inner join t1 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with `Recursive CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE 
AS (
 SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate,  DATEADD(DAY,1,@StartDate) AS NextDate
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,StartDate) AS StartDate, DATEADD(DAY,1,NextDate) AS NextDate
 FROM CTE
 WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,NextDate) <= @EndDate
)
INSERT INTO tblCombinedData
     SELECT 
         a.SomeString
        ,b.SomeNumber
        ,dbo.fnDoSomeStuff(a.AKey, CTE.StartDate, CTE.NextDate)
        ,dbo.fnDoSomeMoreStuff(b.AKey, CTE.StartDate, CTE.NextDate)
    FROM  tblATable a 
    INNER JOIN tblAnotherTable b ON a.ID = b.ID
    CROSS JOIN CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be better handled with a Calendar table, but if you must use something to generate the dates on demand then this would do:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170101';
declare @thrudate date = '20170110';

;with dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
     InsertDate=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
   , NextDate  =convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))  ,@fromdate))
  from master..spt_values a cross join master..spt_values b
  order by 1
)
insert into tblCombinedData
select 
    a.SomeString
  , b.SomeNumber
  , dbo.fnDoSomeStuff(a.akey,d.InsertDate,d.NextDate)
  , dbo.fnDoSomeMoreStuff(b.akey,d.InsertDate,d.NextDate)
from tblatable a 
  inner join tblAnotherTable b 
    on a.id = b.id
  cross join dates d;
```

This does not use a *recursive* [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)(cte), just a regular cte. Using a *recursive* cte to generate a sequence of is one slowest ways to generate a set or sequence without a loop.

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops 2- Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)